# PowerShell return list of PST folders and number of emails in each

Tags: powershell, outlook, pst

I am trying to run a PowerShell script which opens an Outlook PST, and lists all the directories and the number of emails in each of them.  When I first tried it, it worked fine, but as I modified the script it eventually broke.

At this point, even when I revert to the original script, I can't get it to work.  The problem seems to be that when the script tries to set $PST (line 56 of attached file), it is null.  I then get an error message indicating there is a problem due to a null-valued expression.

```
 You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
 At H:\users\michael\my documents\~mga outlook pst email\PST Number of Emails.pst:53 char:27
 + $root = $PST.GetRootFolder <<<< <>
      + CategiryUbfi             : InvalidOperation: (GetRootFolder:String) [], RuntimeException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

The code can be seen here:  https://pastebin.com/embed_js/hGDZwhDd  which is a slight enhancement of https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Count-number-of-emails-in-61a2748e

I think the problem is that the line below does not produced the needed value:

```
 $PST = $objnamespace.stores | ? { $_.FilePath -eq $strPSTPath }
 }
```

If I knew what $PST was supposed to be, I could hard code it as a temporary fix, but I have no idea what the code is trying to do.  Is $PST a variable or an object?

Something which may or may not be related, is that after running the script a few time, several new files appear, with vairents of the PST file name.  If simply removed, the script hangs at an earlier point.  In order to stop the script from looking for these files, I told Outlook the names were the same as the basic PST file.  That seems to work, but with the same "$PST is null" related error.

How to fix/hack?

Answer (score 0):

there are few lines I found not really working and which I would suggest to change. Nevertheless I updated your code and pasted it [here](https://pastebin.com/Dasfqc1q). Go through it and try to run it. Please let me know what's the output. Seems to me that the PST file you refer to does not exist ;)

Here's code I changed to check for file existence

```
$FileExists = Test-Path $strPSTPath 
  if ($FileExists -eq $True) {
  Write-Host "PST Exists"
}
else {
  Write-Host "PST NOT FOUND! Press any key to continue ..."
  $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho, IncludeKeyDown')
}
```

Cheers,
Stanislav

Comment: Of course the PST file, is one that I have.  You would have to change that to one that you have.

Comment: It looks like the main none diagnostic/editorial change you made was to change "
$PST = $objnamespace.stores | ? { $_.FilePath -eq $sT = $objnamespace.stores | Where-Object { $_.FilePath -eq $strPSTPath"..  Can you provide some insight into this line of code?  This change eliminated the fatal error, but the script only outputs information on 3 folders vice the 100's that are in my file.  If you change the $strPSPPath variable to a PST you have on your system, you will see the results.  There should be an output line for each folder in the PST file.

Comment: I also noticed you deleted the non comment line  in "#count items in PST Root  $rootcount = $root.items.count"  Whle that does not seem to have any effect right now, I suspect it will be needed to make the script work correctly.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: In looking at this some more, it seems clear that $PST is an object, and that the original code set the object to include all the folders in the PST, and further that the suggestion of changing the ? to "Where-Object" reduces the $PST object to include only the 3 directories (at least in my case).  Does anyone know what the original code was supposed to do, and why it is not working now (at least for me)?  Please note that it did work at one time (for me) but something has changed so it no longer does.

Comment: Additional information:  the script provided by Stanislav returns an object for $PST for some PST files, but not for others.  I really need some insight into the "$PST = $objnamespace.stores | ? { $_.FilePath -eq $strPSTPath" statement of the original script.  Also, I found out that the script with the original statement, works for some PST files and not for others?